# Facebook like button in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I need to integrate a facebook like button in my app, I also need a share button. I have been reading many post about this topic, but I didn't realize which is the best solution for this.
Is the Webwiew a good solution? If don't which do you recommend
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Facebook Docs and fill in the fields to get your code:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Comment: i generete the URL. Then I have to put it in a webview?

Comment: Yup, Facebook provides you with many versions of the code. You need to take the HTML 5 or iframe version and put it into webview.